# convert a file path into string

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having an error trying to find a way to replace a string in a directory path with another string

```
sed: Error tryning to read from {directory_path}: It's a directory
```

The shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

R2K_SOURCE="source/"
R2K_PROCESSED="processed/"
R2K_TEMP_DIR=""

echo " Procesando archivos desde $R2K_SOURCE "

for file in $(find $R2K_SOURCE )
do
        if [ -d $file ]
        then
                R2K_TEMP_DIR=$( sed 's/"$R2K_SOURCE"/"$R2K_PROCESSED"/g' $file )
                echo "directorio $R2K_TEMP_DIR"
        else
#               some code executes
                :
        fi
done

# find $R2K_PROCCESED -type f -size -200c -delete
```

i'm understanding that the rror it's in this line

```
R2K_TEMP_DIR=$( sed 's/"$R2K_SOURCE"/"$R2K_PROCESSED"/g' $file )
```

but i don't know how to tell sh that treats $file variable as string and not as a directory object.

Comment: Probably: `R2K_TEMP_DIR=$(echo $file |sed 's/"$R2K_SOURCE"/"$R2K_PROCESSED"/g')` (although you could instruct `find` to find directories & files independently with `-type f` / `-type d`

Comment: @Wrikken it's works now write that like an answer and y will approve your answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: Loetar's answer is more correct then my quick remark ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't use:

```
for item in $(find ...)
```

because you might overload the command line. Besides, the for loop cannot start until the process in `$(...)` finishes. Instead:

```
find ... | while read item
```

You also need to watch out for funky file names. The `for` loop will cough on all files with spaces in them. THe `find | while` will work as long as files only have a single space in their name and not double spaces. Better:

```
find ... -print0 | while read -d '' -r item
```

This will put nulls between file names, and `read` will break on those nulls. This way, files with spaces, tabs, new lines, or anything else that could cause problems can be read without problems.

Your sed line is:

```
R2K_TEMP_DIR=$( sed 's/"$R2K_SOURCE"/"$R2K_PROCESSED"/g' $file )
```

What this is attempting to do is edit your `$file` which is a directory. What you want to do is munge the directory name itself. Therefore, you have to echo the name into `sed` as a pipe:

```
R2K_TEMP_DIR=$(echo $file | sed 's/"$R2K_SOURCE"/"$R2K_PROCESSED"/g')
```

However, you might be better off using environment variable parameters to filter your environment variable.

Basically, you have a directory called `source/` and all of the files you're looking for are under that directory. You simply want to change:

```
 source/foo/bar
```

to

```
 processed/foo/bar
```

You could do something like this ${file#source/}. The `#` says this is a *left side* filter and it will remove the least amount to match the glob expression after the `#`. Check the manpage for `bash` and look under *Parameter Expansion*.

This, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

R2K_SOURCE="source/"
R2K_PROCESSED="processed/"
R2K_TEMP_DIR=""

echo " Procesando archivos desde $R2K_SOURCE "

find $R2K_SOURCE -print0 | while read -d '' -r file
do
    if [ -d $file ]
    then
        R2K_TEMP_DIR="processed/${file#source/}"
        echo "directorio $R2K_TEMP_DIR"
    else
#       some code executes
        :
    fi
done
```

`R2K_TEMP_DIR="processed/${file#source/}"` removes the `source/` from the start of `$file` and you merely prepend `processed/` in its place.

Even better, it's way more efficient. In your original script, the `$(..)` creates another shell process to run your `echo` in which then pipes out to another process to run `sed`. (Assuming you use [loentar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222814/368630)'s solution). You no longer have any subprocesses running. The whole modification of your directory name is internal.

By the way, this should also work too:

```
R2K_TEMP_DIR="$R2K_PROCESSED/${file#$R2K_SOURCE}"
```

I just didn't test that.

Comment: using this kind of string substitution ´R2K_TEMP_DIR="$R2K_PROCESSED/${file#$R2K_SOURCE}"´ how can i remove file extention from the filepath based on a extension patters ex (.mib,.MIB,.my) etc.. my last attempt it's R2K_NEW_FILE="${$R2K_TEMP_DIR%$MIB_EXTENTIONS}"
 where MIB_EXTENTION=".mib|.MIB|.my"

Comment: These are globs and not regular expressions. You could do `${file%.*}` and that will remove all extensions. You could also do `${file%.*(mib|MIB|my)}` to remove only certain expressions. Note that it's `*(ext1|ext2|ext3)`, and in BASH, you have to `shopt -s extglob` in order to use these extended expressions.

Answer (score 8):

If you want ot replace part of path name you can echo path name and take it to sed over pipe.
Also you must enable globbing by placing sed commands into double quotes instead of single and change separator for 's' command like that:

```
R2K_TEMP_DIR=$(echo "$file" | sed "s:$R2K_SOURCE:$R2K_PROCESSED:g")
```

Then you will be able to operate with slashes inside 's' command.

**Update:**

Even better is to remove useless echo and use "here is string" instead:

```
R2K_TEMP_DIR=$(sed "s:$R2K_SOURCE:$R2K_PROCESSED:g" <<< "$file")
```